# How to force web page to have same scale in all devices?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, webview

My web page need to be shown in an app. When it shows in the Android version, it is like 3 times larger than in iOS version.

It is probably due to the settings in each app's webview, but I don't made the app so I can't change anything about it. The only thing I can change is my web page, which is a javascript Google Map, the map marker became super large in the Android app.

So is there a thing that I can force my web page to have same scale regardless of the webview settings or app settings?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot, your web page must be developed in the way to fit all screens by codes like -

1. vw/vh, % etc
2. media screens configurations

Your devices cannot control the contents of web page from outside unless they are designed so.

Answer (score 0):

If its a web page try adding this to head tag of your HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,  width=device-width">
```